# Snubber circuit to protect SCR/Diode

Tags: switches, protection, inductive, snubber, scr

In my circuit I need to discharge a capacitor into an inductive load using SCR. In order to make the circuit oscillate there'll be a diode antiparallel with the SCR, as you can see in the picture.

[image]

My plan is to let the circuit oscillate only one sine wave cycle and then stop (I'll turn off the SCR as soon the current stops flowing through the SCR and starts flowing through the diode).
My question is: do I need to use a snubber circuit parallel with the SCR/Diode to protect it from voltage peaks?
I know that snubber circuits are needed for switching, mainly when the load is inductive, but in this case there's a diode that can conduct when there's reverse voltage peaks, as far as I understand.
I've tried to simulate it but the results doesn't make much sense to me.
Consider the capacitor is charged when the SCR is triggered.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally it goes in parallel with the inductor. But how do you expect it to oscillate when an SCR only conducts in one direction? Or is that the reason for the diode? So it provides a path for current to flow from the L back to the C around the SCR? I initially though you were asking if D2 was the snubber, but it occurs to me now that maybe this was not your intention.

Comment: Where is your power source? Q will depend on L/R values where R is the diode resistance at average current.

Comment: DKNguyen, that's the reason for the diode! But I'm wondering if I still need a snubber circuit even if I use this diode there.

Comment: Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy, sorry, I made this poor circuit for illustration. Please consider the capacitor will be initially charged when I trigger the SCR.
In my actual design, there will be a DC source that charges the capacitor and then there'll be a switch to disconnect the DC source from the capacitor, so the LC circuit can oscillate normally.

Comment: Well, if you plan on letting it oscillate until it dies out then you don't need any snubber since the SCR must be on the entire time it is oscillating and only turns off when there is no more current flowing. If you plan on using the SCR to interrupt a current, then you need a snubber. D2 snubs nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My plan is to let only a full sine wave cycle oscillate, and then turn off the SCR. In fact I would turn off the SCR as soon as the current crosses zero, so there'll be enough time to SCR turn off completely.
In this case is it important to use the snubber circuit then?

Comment: What diode are you using? A common 1N400X diode may turn off slow and allow enough reverse current to flow to cause an issue. I don't know how well CircuitLab models reverse recovery, but I am seeing a big negative spike at L1. A 1N4937 would probably fix it, but the simulator doesn't have one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mattman944. Do you mean that when the SCR is off, the diode might allow current that would cause spikes of voltage over the inductor? So should I use diodes with both low reverse recovery time and low reverse current?
In fact I haven't choose the diode yet, but I want to generate a big magnetic field pulse in the coil, so the capacitor might be charged with more than 1kV (the current is gonna be huge). I had not think about the reverse current across the diode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a snubber then. Also, SCRs latch on and cannot turn themselves off once on. So as long as the trigger signal is removed when the current crosses zero, the SCR will turn off on its own.

Actually now that I reminded myself about that, an SCR can't interrupt current even if you wanted it to so a snubber is pointless. The SCR can only turn off when the current becomes zero due to external means anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
During the negative cycle of the sinusoidal current (when the diode is conducting), the voltage across both diode and SCR I'll be the diode forward voltage (0.7 usually)? I'm afraid that the SCR don't turn off because of insuficient reverse voltage (and also there'll be a short period of time for the SCR to turn off, It'll be half of the period of the LC oscillator if I'm not wrong).

Comment: @LucasRibeiroBarzotto Hmmmmm. I see your concerns. I can't really opine on that since I've never tried using SCRs in such a way. It is true that SCRs are rather slow and it is true that the 0.7V might cause issues. Your SCR datasheet should help provide some insight.